# R generate multiple Excel files from a dataset, based on conditions from another

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I've got a dataset with feedback comments on multiple criteria from a customer survey conducted on many sites, where each row represents a single response.

For simplicity's sake, I have simplified the original dataset and produced a reproducible dataframe with comments for only three sites.

The criteria are listed from columns 4 - 10.

```
comments = data.frame(RESPONDENT_ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
             REGION=c("ASIA","ASIA","ASIA","ASIA","ASIA","EUROPE","EUROPE","EUROPE"),
             SITE=c("Tokyo Center","Tokyo Center","Tokyo Center","PB Tower","PB Tower","Rome Heights","Rome Heights","Rome Heights"),
             Lighting=c("Dim needs to be better","","Good","I don't like it","Could be better","","",""),
             Cleanliness=c("","very clean I'm happy","great work","","disappointed","I like the work","","nice"),
             Hygiene=c("","happy","needs improvement","great","poor not happy","nice!!","clean as usual i'm never disappointed",""),
             Service=c("great service","impressed","could do better","","","need to see more","cant say","meh"),
             Punctuality=c("always on time","","loving it","proper and respectful","","","punctual as always","delays all the time!"),
             Efficiency=c("generally efficient","never","cannot comment","","","","","happy with this"),
             Motivation=c("always very motivated","driven","exceeds expectations","","poor service","ok can do better","hmm","motivated"))
```

I've got a second dataset, which contains the bottom 3 scoring criteria for each of the three sites.

```
bottom = data.frame(REGION=c("ASIA","ASIA","EUROPE"),
             SITE=c("Tokyo Center","PB Tower","Rome Heights"),
             BOTTOM_1=c("Lighting","Cleanliness","Motivation"),
             BOTTOM_2=c("Hygiene","Service","Lighting"),
             BOTTOM_3=c("Motivation","Punctuality","Cleanliness"))
```

**My Objective:**

1) From the `comments` dataframe, for each `SITE`, I'd like to filter the `bottom` dataframe, and extract the comments for the bottom 3 criteria per site only.

2) Based on this extraction, for each unique `SITE`, I'd like to create an Excel file with three sheets, each sheet named after the bottom 3 criteria for that given site.

3) Each Sheet would contain a list of comments extracted for that particular site.

4) I'd like all Excel files saved in the format:

> *REGION*_*SITE*_Comments2017.xlsx

**Desired Final Output:**

3 Excel files (or as many files as there are unique sites), each Excel file having three tabs named after their bottom 3 criteria, and each sheet with a list of comments corresponding to the given criterion for that site.

**So as an example, one of the three files generated would look like this:**

- The file name would be ASIA_TokyoCenter_Comments2017.xlsx
- The file would contain 3 sheets, "Lighting","Hygiene" & "Motivation" (based on the three bottom criteria for this site)
- Each of these sheets would contain their respective site-level comments.

**My Methodology:**

I tried using a `for` loop on the `comments` dataframe, and filtering the `bottom` dataframe for each site listed.

Then using the `write.xlsx` function from the `xlsx` package to generate the Excel files, with the `sheetName` argument set to each of the bottom three citeria per site.

However I cannot seem to get the desired results. I have searched on Stackoverflow for similar solutions, but haven't found anything yet.

Any help with this would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably can be formatted better... 
But for each level in Region and Site, for each 'bottom', we extract each independent combination and write to file.

```
bottom <- sapply(bottom, as.character) # Get out of factors.
sp <- split(comments, comments$REGION) # Split data into a list format for ease.
for(i in unique(bottom[,1])){
   for(j in unique(bottom[,2])){
       x <- sp[[1]][sp[[i]][,3]==j,]
       y <-  x[,colnames(x)%in%bottom[bottom[,1]==i& bottom[,2]==j,3:5]]
       for(q in colnames(y)){
       if(nrow(x) > 0) {
         write.xlsx(x=y[,q],
                    file=paste(i,j, 'Comments2017.xlsx', sep='_'),
                    sheetName=q, append=T)
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: This seems quite close, but the final files do not seem to be in the right format. After testing your code, I see that each sheet is not named after a single 'bottom' criterion. And each sheet seems to contain 3 criteria instead of one. And these criteria do not seem to correspond to those listed in the bottom dataframe for the given site.

Comment: @Varun Your question (regarding how the results should look) wasn't exactly clear in the first place. I have updated my answer so that the code now produces spreadsheet according to bottom_3 and separates each question into its own sheet. I am afraid you will either need to be more clear regarding what you want. Or use the frame-work I have provided to generate the output you want.

Comment: Thanks @TJGorrie, and apologies if I wasn't clear in my explanation. I've updated the original question to include an example under the Desired Output part. I tested your updated code, now I have the three tabs named after their respective tabs. This is exactly what I wanted. However  the three criteria don't seem to correspond exactly to those listed in the 'bottom' dataframe for a given site, i.e. I seem to have some criteria that don't belong in the 'bottom' dataframe for a given site.

Comment: it seems to be giving me an error message: Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: @Varun I have fixed the code. It runs on my end perfectly.

Comment: One last question for you @TJGorrie. What does this line signify x <- sp[[1]][sp[[i]][,3]==j,]  and how would I adapt the code if I were to increase the 'bottom' criteria to 5, instead of 3?

Comment: @Varun if you want the bottom five you will change this line: y <-  `x[,colnames(x)%in%bottom[bottom[,1]==i& bottom[,2]==j,3:5]]` to 3:n (e.g. 3:7). The line you have quoted is simply extracting the rows that satisfy Region and Site.

Comment: Thanks again @TJGorrie. Each sheet contains the comments I need, but also contains rows with empty cells (no comments). Is there a way the code can be modified to exclude those rows that contain blanks?